# call function in 'code behind' with AJAX in ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax, vb.net

I want to get access to a method in code behind when I clicked an span in my view aspx:

**DEFAULT.ASPX VIEW CODE:**

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<%-- MY SPAN --%>
 <span runat="server" onclick="ShowChartSpider(this.id)" id="group_2" style="cursor: pointer" class="pull-right">My Span</span>


<%-- JAVASCRIPT CODE --%>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowChartSpider(group_id) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/MethodToCreateChart",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{'parameter1':" + JSON.stringify(group_id) + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                

                success: function (data) {
                    alert("all correct");
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("no");
                }
            }
            );
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

**DEFAULT.ASPX.VB CODE BEHIND:**

```
<WebMethod()>
    <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
    Public Shared Sub MethodToCreateChart(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ' My code to create the chart .....
    End Sub
```

if I run the page, and inspects the page with the browser to see errors, none appear, but the code does not reach the breakpoint that I put in the method in codebehind.

What I´m doing wrong?
I would appreciate suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Check new updated code

Answer (score 1):

First check your server allow non HTTPS request.
i had that type of issue and my server didn't allow me to do that.
it so then disable that and test.

Then check the response status.

```
error: function(xhr, status) {
alert(xhr.status); }
```

let us know that is the outcome.

--Ruhul

Comment: I get the alert for success, not for error, but what I said, the code does not reach the breakpoint that I put in the method in codebehind. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Go to "RouteConfig.vb" under "App_Start" folder.

Change following line

```
 settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent
```

To

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off
```

i think your method code returning something like this.

Return Default.aspx/MethodToCreateChart

so me your MethodToCreateChart logic.

you can try with below sample method. your internal server error are coming because you are returning somethng from your method.

```
Public Shared Function MethodToCreateChart(parameter1 As String) As String

   Return "Hello " & Environment.NewLine & "The Current Time is: " & _DateTime.Now.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: is not work, but I tried to put this in the ajax method:   url: "Default.aspx", and works but only reaches the load of the page, so the problem is in the path, but I don´t know how to fix it

Comment: Remove this line.  <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>

Comment: I get this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://localhost:4984/Default.aspx/MethodToCreateChart

Comment: You check my new code? Because in my project your code is working, breakpoint hit in the method in codebehind part.

Comment: can you zip your proyect , to download it?

Comment: You just replace your code to my code and just check that. This is the method "Public Shared Function..."

Comment: I get this alert message with the error function:                                               error: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }                                                                                                       browser message error ------>    [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove 'runat=server' attribute from span tag.

Comment: I remove the runat server from the span, but it does not work :-(

Answer (score 0):

You use aspx file same as ashx files. So have a look at below links:
1. [How do you debug ASP.net HTTPHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194035/how-do-you-debug-asp-net-httphandler)
2. [Can't debug ASHX handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202903/c-cant-debug-ashx-handler)